# spring-dev-tools does not reloading changes in project, Intellij idea

Tags: spring-boot-devtools

Maven dependency spring-boot-devtools does not reloading changes in a project automatically.

I have solved this problem by changing parameters of "**running configuration**".

**Go to edit configuration**->
*In the Spring boot section you will see* -

**Running Application Update Polices** - options

change - "**On 'Update' action** - to -> Update trigger file
and - "**On frame deactivation** - to -> Update classes and resources.

Apply changes and press OK.

Answer (score 7):

The problem has been fixed for me after following the below steps.

Please go to the Top Right Corner of your "**IntelliJ IDE**" and then click on the **ellipsis** symbol (three vertical dots)->choose "**Configure Edit Tabs**"

1. Expand "**Build, Execution and Deployment**" -> Compiler-> **Check** the option "**Build Project Automatically**"
2. Click on "**Advanced Settings**" -> Select the Check the option under **Compiler**
   -> "**Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running**"

Please note that I'm using the "**IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2**" version.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this problem by changing parameters of "running configuration".

Go to edit configuration-> In the Spring boot section you will see -

Running Application Update Polices - options

change - "On 'Update' action - to -> Update trigger file and - "On frame deactivation - to -> Update classes and resources.

Apply changes and press OK.

Comment: I want to have your children :D. Been trying for months to fix this.

Comment: agree -  but not the bit about having his children.